# ImageButton OnClick (Programmatically) firing, but not allowing for checkpoints - Walkthrough shows OnClick Event not stepable

Tags: c#, onclick, imagebutton

Assignment Place #1:

```
                case 1:
                    TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                    if (!strlil_image_1.Contains("blank"))
                    {
                        var img = new ImageButton();
                        img.ID = "imglil_image_" + strlil_image_1.Replace("images/inventory/", String.Empty).Replace(".", "_");
                        img.AlternateText = "Image " + i.ToString();
                        img.ImageUrl = strlil_image_1;
                        img.Width = 40;
                        img.Height = 40;
                        img.Click += img_Click;
                        tCell.Controls.Add(img);
                }
                else
                {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.ID = "imglil_image_" + i.ToString();
                    img.AlternateText = "Image " + i.ToString();
                    img.ImageUrl = strlil_image_1;
                    img.Width = 40;
                    img.Height = 40;
                    tCell.Controls.Add(img);
                }

                tRow1.Cells.Add(tCell);
                break;
```

Assignment Place #2:

```
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                if (arrList[i].mark_color_group)
                {
                    tCell.Style.Add("border", "1px solid brown");
                    imgMainPic.ImageUrl = arrList[i].image_name.ToString();
                }

                var img = new ImageButton();
                img.ID = "imglil_color_group_" + arrList[i].color_id;
                img.AlternateText = "Image " + arrList[i].color_id;
                img.ImageUrl = arrList[i].image_name;
                img.Width = 40;
                img.Height = 40;
                img.Click += img_Click;
                tCell.Controls.Add(img);

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
```

Associated Function:

```
protected void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    getData();

    ImageButton clickedbutton = sender as ImageButton;
    String strbtn = String.Empty;
    int intbtn = 0;
    int inttype = 0;

    if (clickedbutton.ID.Contains("imglil_color_group_"))
    {
        inttype = 1;
    }

    if (clickedbutton.ID.Contains("imglil_image_"))
    {
        inttype = 2;
    }

    switch (inttype)
    {
        case 1:
            //determine id - color group in the middle of the detail td
            strbtn = clickedbutton.ID.Replace("imglil_color_group_", String.Empty);
            intbtn = Convert.ToInt32(strbtn);

            drawLilImagesTable(intbtn.ToString(), false);
            break;
        case 2:
            //determine id - lil picture on the left, putting src into big pic
            strbtn = clickedbutton.ID.Replace("imglil_image_", String.Empty);
            strbtn = strbtn.Replace("_", ".");
            //intbtn = Convert.ToInt32(strbtn);

            imgMainPic.ImageUrl = strbtn;
            break;
    }
}
```

When the page initially runs, the ImageButton draws, with proper image, cursor=hand, etc. When clicked, page cycles, Page_Load (child and Master) loads, but then, when stepping through the code, the function for the ImageButton is not run. This is where I am stumped.

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you make the local img to a Image at

```
            else
            {
                var img = new Image();
                img.ID = "imglil_image_" + i.ToString();
                img.AlternateText = "Image " + i.ToString();
                img.ImageUrl = strlil_image_1;
                img.Width = 40;
                img.Height = 40;
                tCell.Controls.Add(img);
            }

            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCell);
            break;
```

and then breaks?  the Event is never assigned. Is the condition for the If before the else never true?

Comment: 1) The code causes no errors.
2) The ImageButton displays "correctly".
3) When I click the ImageButton, the page posts.
4) But when I follow the flow of debugging, the code does not go to the function that I tell it to.
5) Other functionality, like a DropDownList changing option, run without error.
6) Help!!!